# WinApi: Закрепить часть области окна при скроллинге

Tags: c++, winapi

Пытаюсь Закрепить часть области окна при скроллинге, ну то есть, знаете, как в екселе верхняя строка закрепляется, чтобы она была фиксированная и чтобы при прокрутке данных всегда оставалась видимо, а не прокручивалсь вместе с остальными данными:

И вроде бы получается, но получается, как то не совсем правильно:

Сколллинг осуществляю при помощи функции: `ScrollWindowEx`, в структуре `RECT_` - как раз указывается та область окна, которая должна прокрутчиватся, остальная часть соответственно не прокручивается:

```
RECT_k.left = 0;
RECT_right = 800;
RECT_.top = 200;
RECT_.bottom = 2000;
 
ScrollWindowEx(hWnd, 0, Y_offset, &RECT_, NULL, NULL, NULL, SW_ERASE | SW_INVALIDATE | SW_SCROLLCHILDREN);
```

Есть обычное стандартно созданное окно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я делаю скроллинг вниз: как видно кнопки 0,1,2 ушли, как бы за отсеченную область, причем кнопки Add и My_button остались на месте...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И все бы было классно, но, когда я делаю скролл обратно вверх, то получается вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И когда полностью разворачиваю окно, то оказывается 0,1 - куда то пропали, а между кнопками 2 и 3 появилось вообще какое то пространство.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но куда деваются кнопки и почему дочернее окно в виде кнопки вообще меняет свои координаты расположения - что то не могу понять.

Comment: Нужно закрепленное окно ставить не в "панель" котороя скроллируется, а в её родителя. "Панель" с скроллированием отдельно должна быть. А грань стыковка - можно убрать если мешает.

Comment: nick_n_a, подскажите, что значит не в "панель" ? У меня одно Родительское окно и дочерние кнопки. Функцию ScrollWindowEx - я применяю именно к Родительскому окну.

Comment: Тогда создаёте ещё одно окно с parentid родительского, именно на него размещаете все елементы которые нужно скроллировать, и скролл делаете не родительскому, а данному. Если не пользуетесь либами - то вручную задаёте ему нужный размер и расположение. Если работаете через "визуалку" то это называется панель.

Comment: С точки зрения концепции окна, лично мне не понятно как можно прокрутить часть окна. Можно "показать" что прокрутилась часть окна в нужном прямоугольнике - согласен, но физически прокручиватся весь контекст, что становится понятно после обновления окна системой. Поэтому что бы не ловить глюки - создавайте отдельно окно в окне - и в нём прокручивайте контекст.